# How to add multiple ips to a iptables shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, iptables

I am trying to creating shell script to block some ips whether the below one is the right way to do it

```
   #!/bin/bash 
   iptables 
   -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.xx/29 -j DROP
   -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -j DROP
```

I am trying to save this and execute it as a1.sh but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make those into valid `iptables` commands:

```
#!/bin/bash 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.xx/29 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -d xx.xx.xx.xx/32 -j DROP
```

Note that those commands block outgoing connections.  It is more common for firewalls to block incoming connections.

Also, for some uses, you may prefer to consider `-j REJECT` in place of `-j DROP`.  `DROP` will just silently drop the packet while the `REJECT` action will notify the sender that the packet will not go through.

Comment: I did that but it's not getting added to iptables (I am executing the shell script in Android)

Comment: @Shan OK.  What makes you think that the rules were not added to `iptables`?  Did you run `iptables -L` and examine the output?  Also, did the above commands generate any error messages when run?

Comment: They didn't generate any error..I examined using iptables -L and they were not there

Comment: I was not using the right editor for writing .sh script..used Notepad++ with EOL conversion now it's working fine..thanks

Answer (score 0):

"iptables" is a command. Commands take optional arguments. The arguments must follow the command in the same line.

```
iptables -A ...
iptables -A ...
```